# Сравнение дат соседних записей в одной таблице SQL (Oracle DB)

Tags: sql, oracle

Имеется следующая таблица:

```
CREATE table "Sessiya"(  
"faculty" NVARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL,
"course" NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL,
"discipline" NUMBER(5,2) NOT NULL,
"group" NVARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,
"type" NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
"prepodavatel" NVARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL,
"auditory" NUMBER(3),
"timedate" DATE,
constraint "pk_Sessiya" primary key("discipline","group","type"),
constraint "fk_Prepodavateli" foreign key ("prepodavatel")
references "Prepodavateli"("name")
);
```

Нужно вытащить разницы соседних дат("timedate", сортировка по возрастанию) для определенной группы (или для каждой).

**Вопрос**: можно ли это сделать **запросом**? (через GROUP BY или как-то еще)

Пока накидал такой вот код, который выдает нужный результат:

```
    --1)Проверить, проходит ли у каждой группы между двумя экзаменами не менее трёх дней. 
    SET serveroutput ON
    DECLARE
        TYPE GenericCursor IS REF CURSOR;
        Dates GenericCursor;
        Groups GenericCursor;
        DateCur DATE;
        DatePrev DATE;
        GoodDates BOOLEAN; 
        Diff INTEGER;
        Gr NVARCHAR2(5);

    BEGIN
        OPEN Groups FOR SELECT DISTINCT "group" FROM "Sessiya";
        LOOP
            GoodDates:=TRUE;
            fetch Groups into Gr;
            EXIT WHEN Groups%NOTFOUND;
            dbms_output.put_line('__________________');
            dbms_output.put('Группа: ');
            dbms_output.put_line(Gr);
            dbms_output.put_line('__________________');
            OPEN Dates FOR 
                SELECT "timedate" FROM "Sessiya"
                WHERE "group"=Gr
                ORDER BY "timedate" ASC;
            fetch Dates into DateCur;
            LOOP
                DatePrev:= DateCur;
                fetch Dates into DateCur;
                EXIT WHEN Dates%NOTFOUND;
                Diff:=DateCur-DatePrev;
                if Diff<3 then
                    dbms_output.put_line('Меньше 3 дней между:');
                    dbms_output.put_line(DatePrev);
                    dbms_output.put_line(DateCur);
                    GoodDates:=FALSE;
                end if;
            END LOOP;--Цикл по датам
            CLOSE Dates;
            if GoodDates=TRUE then
                dbms_output.put_line('У данной группы даты в порядке');
            end if;
        END LOOP;--Цикл по группам
        CLOSE Groups;
    END;
    /
```

Результат:

```
    __________________
    Группа: 41-12
    __________________
    Меньше 3 дней между:
    15.01.16
    17.01.16
    Меньше 3 дней между:
    20.01.16
    21.01.16
    __________________
    Группа: 21-13
    __________________
    У данной группы даты в порядке
```

P.S.: Заранее извиняюсь за неправильное использование инструментов

Comment: Думаю, что функции LAG/LEAD решат проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разницу можно получить так:

```
SELECT "timedate" - lag("timedate") over(ORDER BY "timedate" ASC)
  FROM "Sessiya"
 WHERE "group"=Gr
```

Оконная функция `LAG()` возвращает как раз дату из предыдущей записи в порядке сортировки, указанном в предложении `over()`. В предложении WHERE нельзя использовать оконные функции, поэтому если потребуется отбор по разности дат, данный запрос надо будет обернуть в еще один.

Answer (score 0):

Если кому интересно (вдруг я сам буду гуглить через год), то вот код, который почти полностью решает мою задачу:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT "group","timedate","timedate" - LAG("timedate") OVER(ORDER BY "group","timedate" ASC) AS "difference"
        FROM "Sessiya"
)
WHERE "difference">3;
```

> Спасибо всем за помощь и наводки)